# Modifying web.config with powershell to have smtp section

Tags: powershell, web-config, smtp

I'm trying to modify the web.config with powershell to add a smtp section. I saw this post : 
http://ybbest.wordpress.com/2012/02/28/how-to-add-configuration-settings-using-spwebconfigmodification-and-powershell-script/#comment-1070
which add some appsettings defining smtp section. But I want to know if these line:

```
<add key="businessSupportEmailAddress" value="contosointergenfax@gmail.com" />
<add key="copyMoveTempFolder" value="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\SharePointProducts" />
<add key="faxEmailAddress" value="contosointergenfax@gmail.com" />
<add key="fromEmailAccount" value="contosoAdmin" />
<add key="fromEmailAddress" value="contosointergenfax@gmail.com" />
<add key="smtpServerName" value="build.contoso.local" />
<add key="smtpServerPort" value="25" />
```

are the same as this :

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
<smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="testuser@domail.com">
<network defaultCredentials="true" host="localhost" port="25" userName="kaushal" password="testPassword"/>
</smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Thanks

Comment: same as? missing something here!

Comment: Indeed something was missing, sry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.

First block represents key,value pairs that will be loaded in the default hash by the Configuration Manager  (appSettings, see http://odetocode.com/Articles/345.aspx).

The other one is the .NET system config for mailing, mostly used in ASP webapps : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/w355a94k.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for visiting my [blog](http://ybbest.wordpress.com) and my solution is specific to a SharePoint project we are working on.In the end we actually end up putting the configuration settings into a list as we need the SharePoint timer job to access the configuration settings too.

If your solution is asp.net application , you should use the latter.